# Overloading methods that return a Task<T>

Tags: c#, async-await

Maybe I'm overthinking, but what is the proper way of overloading methods that are async and return a Task of T?

Say I have a method with signature `async Task<int> Method1(string input, string secondInput)` and I want to overload it with `async Task<int> Method2(string input, string secondInput, string thirdInput)`, should the second method body just look like this?

```
return await Method1(input, secondInput+thirdInput);
```

My question is, can I just await it like this and not raise any unexpected behaviour for a consumer? Would this be the same as the consumer calling the Method1 and concatinating strings themself?

Comment: You can just do `return Method1(input, ...);` without async and await.

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html

Comment: Does the `secondInput + thirdInput` operation represents the actual (or intended, or expected) functionality that the three-arguments overload will provide? Or it's possible that the actual functionality will be more complex, potentially throwing exceptions that the two-argument overload would never throw?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias no, the actual functionality I want to achieve is practically as simple as it is, no potential exceptions.

Comment: Then you probably have a legitimate case for [eliding async await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html). If you don't have any performance considerations then don't elide, it's safer.